# Poisson distribution (?) word problem.

Tags: probability, statistics

Here's my problem:

> Tech support receives 10 calls on average in 30 minutes. What's the probability to receive more than 2 calls in the next 30 minutes?

Answer from my textbook: 0.997.

I assume that a Poisson distribution should be used and using this formula:

$P(X = x) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}.\lambda^x}{x!}$

I get:

$\lambda$ = 10 calls/30 min = 1/3

$P(X > 2) = 1 - {{\frac13}^2\over2!} * e^{-1/3}$

Which is equal to 0.96019.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here $P(X>2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$

Comment: Ok this clarified a few things for me, but the answer I'm getting now is even further from the correct one. [Do I do this?](http://i.imgur.com/S2QbUpO.png). Sorry I am bad at this and confused. Will have to revisit previous material looks like.

Comment: Another mistake is that the number of calls in the next 30 minutes is Poisson with parameter 10, not parameter 10/30. This leads to the probability $1-61e^{-10}\approx0.9972306$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it now :)